# Stylish Javascript progress (loading) bar...?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, loading, indicator

Im currently developing a car related website in which I want to create a very stylish progress bar with javascript (not flash). I want it to look similar to a speed indicator, like this: http://www.crestock.com/images/1260000-1269999/1260687-xs.jpg

So I have done great couple of Google searches for javascript bars but only found simple horizontal bars.

Any ideas of how I should proceed?

Comment: Im willing to use jquery obviously.

Answer (score 0):

give [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/) a shot. It has some rich effects and UI widgets.

Grtz

EDIT:
I came across this one:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/charts/Gauge.html

Comment: Looks interesting, however its a horizontal type of progress bar, would it be complicated to remake it to the style that I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually quite doable - see this article on CSS3 rotation and filters in Internet Explorer, and also search for the CSS3 Transform property - http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/04/05/cross-browser-animated-css-transforms-even-in-ie/

Although I would state right here and then that whatever purpose you might have use for a Javascript loading bar be 90% of the time it can't be good. If your page is so big that it'll require a loading bar then you really really should consider a redesign/rewriting of your code and design for the site. The same would be if you want animation *just for the sake of animation*.

But I'm afraid I might have said a little too much - don't let that discourage you from having a look at a very interesting technique, or from using it on whatever you deem necessary. If you need more help just drop a comment on this question.

Comment: Thats excellent! Thank you very much for this helpful respond!

Comment: And also to note, Im not using it to lead the page, its more of a feature to see the speed the cars can reach within a a mile.